# Can MATLAB retrieve online data?

Tags: matlab

I have a final project due soon and am having to create a building calculator GUI.

Inputs will be

- number of floors
- number of bathrooms, and
- square footage

The output shall be the cost in materials to build the home.

One of my goals (which I was told by my TA was doable, then he seemed to not know much about after I went more in depth later) was to **automatically update the cost of each material from a website such as Home Depot's** each time the GUI is run. Building material costs change frequently so I wanted to assign each material its own cost value that is updated automatically from HD's website. Is this something that is possible?

I appreciate any input.

```
RockPrice = urlread('http://www.homedepot.com/p/SHEETROCK-UltraLight-1-2-in-x-4-ft-x-8-ft-Gypsum-Board-14113411708/202530243','Get',{'displayPrice','urlread'})
```

Answer (score 2):

For getting a webpage's content (including all markup), [`urlread`](http://ch.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/urlread.html) can be used. Parsing that string for the data you want ('scraping' it, as some like to call this process) might be non-trivial in MATLAB, though.

Easier to handle would be data from a dedicated API, and Home Depot [seems to actually have a REST API](http://developer.homedepot.com/book-page/catalog-api) that has their product details. All their public APIs seem to still be in private beta, though, so I don't know how successful one would be in requesting an API key.

Comment: How would one go about requesting an API key? Simply emailing them?

Comment: They lay out the process at http://developer.homedepot.com/book-page/obtaining-your-api-key

Comment: I have attempted contacting them and submitting an application. Unfortunately I do not believe I will have time to wait for a response so I am going ahead with the urlread function. If you could assist me in figuring out how to extract the price from the website, it would be most helpful. This is what I have played with so far, but cannot figure out how to only extract the price (being $9.48 in this case) without the rest of the web page following along. I will edit my original post with my current code.

Comment: Sorry, @Carpenterguy, I only found this that MATLAB function by a quick web search, I don't know more about it than what can be read online and I don't have MATLAB installed to try it out myself. StackOverflow is a Q&A site, not a support forum, so if you have specific follow-up questions it might be better to post them as new questions instead of perpetually editing the question here with new subtopics.